# using javascript to loop through asp.net radio button list to get selected value and text

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, radio-button

I am creating a questions and answers page and the answers are a collection of asp.net radiobuttonlist as per the following: `

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Q1AnswersRadioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Q1OptionARadioButton"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Q1OptionBRadioButton"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Q1OptionCRadioButton"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Q1OptionDRadioButton"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                <br />
                &nbsp;<textarea class="text-danger" id="Q1CorrectAnswerText" name="Q1CorrectAnswerText" readonly="readonly" wrap="soft"></textarea>
            </div>
```

Now, I am using the following JavaScript function to loop through to find out which one the user selected. The following is the JavaScript code.

```
function GetUserAnswerOneSelection()
{
var elementRef = document.getElementById('Q1AnswersRadioButtonList');
var radioButtonListArray = elementRef.getElementsByTagName('input');
var checkedValues = '';

for (var i = 0; i < radioButtonListArray.length; i++) {
    var radioButtonRef = radioButtonListArray[i];

    if (radioButtonRef.checked == true) {
        // To get the Text property, use this code:
        var labelArray =   radioButtonRef.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label');
        if (labelArray.length > 0) {
            if (checkedValues.length > 0)
                checkedValues += ', ';
            checkedValues += labelArray[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }
}

userAnswer1 = checkedValues;
return userAnswer1;
```

}

The problem now is, it always breaks on this line     var radioButtonListArray = elementRef.getElementsByTagName('input');
and reports that is undefined.
I need help please.

Comment: Are you sure that `elementRef` is not null here? WebForms has the annoying feature that it will not name your objects with the ID you specify in code.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? Older versions tend to prefix the name of controls with that of their container (and of course the classic "ctl00" stuff) - so your id typed in code could be rendered differently and hence not be found, making elementRef null. With newer versions (4 onward I think) allow you to specify naming conventions when rendering the HTML, so you can set that to "static" for names to be outputted literally.

Comment: which browser ? is it firefox?

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.  Yes it is giving me null. I am using visual studio 2013 community edition.  I don't know what to do.  I am so frustrated for about 3 days now.  Please what should I do?

Comment: I am using internet explorer on windows 10 tech preview, also using firefox, chrome and maxthon

Answer (score 3):

Try to put `ClientIDMode="Static"` in `asp:RadioButtonList` so you are able to get it in Javascript.

or do:

```
var elementRef = document.getElementById('<%= Q1AnswersRadioButtonList.ClientID %>');**
```

Comment: Hi, thank you sir.  But unfortunately am still getting the same error: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: Yes David, I didn't read your options well. I mixed them.  I used the top one and the name and it worked.  Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
function GetUserAnswerOneSelection() {
            var elementRef = document.getElementById("Q1AnswersRadioButtonList");
            var radioButtonListArray = elementRef.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var checkedValues = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < radioButtonListArray.length; i++) {
                var radioButtonRef = radioButtonListArray[i];

                if (radioButtonRef.checked == true) {
                    // To get the Text property, use this code:
                    var labelArray = radioButtonRef.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('label');
                    if (labelArray.length > 0) {
                        if (checkedValues.length > 0)
                            checkedValues += ', ';
                        checkedValues += labelArray[i].innerHTML;
                    }
                }
            }

            userAnswer1 = checkedValues;              
        }

   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Q1AnswersRadioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Q1OptionARadioButton"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Q1OptionBRadioButton"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Q1OptionCRadioButton"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Q1OptionDRadioButton"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Or You can get it in one line using JQuery like

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Q1AnswersRadioButtonList input").click(function () {
                GetUserAnswerOneSelection();

                alert( $("#Q1AnswersRadioButtonList input:checked").next("label").html());
            });

        });
```

Comment: Ajay, I am going to try the jQuery one, it looks simple and nice.

Comment: Hello Bainn, If you think you got your answer then Please Mark it as Answer.